# Custom routes with id attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm confused as to how to sort out routes for my show action.  At the moment if I select on a particular guidelines to 'show' it, the url says

> /guidelines/1

where 1 is the guideline id

I'd like it to say

> /title

(where this is the title of the guideline that is being shown).  I'm confused how to manage this in my routes.  At the moment my routes has

```
get 'guideline/:id', to: 'guidelines#show', as: :seeguideline
```

but this just shows guideline/1 as I mentioned so I realise I'm doing something wrong

My view links to this with

```
<%= link_to guideline.title, seeguideline_path(id: guideline.id) %>
```

show action in guidelines_controller.rb is

```
def show
    @guideline = Guideline.where(title: params[:title]).first
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @guideline }

    end
  end
```

routes are

```
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  devise_for :admin_user, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config


  get "guidelines/topic"
  get "guidelines/topichospital"
  get "guidelines/topicspecialty"
  get "guidelines/favourite"


  devise_for :users

  devise_scope :user do
    get 'signup', to: 'devise/registrations#new', as: :register
    get 'login', to: 'devise/sessions#new', as: :login
    get 'logout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :logout
    get 'edit', to: 'devise/registrations#edit', as: :edit
    put 'users' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => 'user_registration'
    get 'about', to: 'about#about', as: :about
  end

  resources :guidelines
  get 'guidelines', to: 'guidelines#index', as: :guidelines
  get 'favourites', to: "favourites#show", as: :favourites
  get 'topics', to: 'guidelines#list', as: :topics
  get 'hospitals', to: 'guidelines#listhospital', as: :hospitals
  get 'specialties', to: 'guidelines#listspecialty', as: :specialties



  root :to => 'guidelines#index'
  get '/:id', to: 'profiles#show', as: :myprofile
  get '/:title', to: 'guidelines#show', as: :seeguideline
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to match urls like '/url', you need to place this at the bottom of your routes file so it takes the least priority (ie it doesnt match '/projects' if you have a projects controller). in theory this is done via

```
match '/:title' => 'guidelines#show', as: :seeguideline
```

then in your controller

```
def show
  @guideline = Guideline.where(title: params[:title]).first
end
```

then in your views, you can use

```
seeguideline_path(@guideline.title)
```

but you also have to take care of invalid characters in the title to be used in the url.

Comment: thanks - that all makes sense.  But it's not taking me to the right place (i.e going to /title but not loading the guideline show) - it says 'the page you are looking for doesn't exist'

Comment: can you update your question with your routes and your guidelines controller?

Comment: this line `get '/:id', to: 'profiles#show', as: :myprofile` overrides the route you added so instead of going to the guidelines controller, it will go to profiles controller.

Comment: ah, ok, but that's for something else - am I able to use them both?

Comment: you are right, when I delete that line the titles function works.  But what should I do to have them both work?

Comment: you can but you have to use constraints so only certain urls match `/:id`.  if `/:id` and `/:title` have even the slightest chance of being the same, you can't.  will `/:id` be always a number?

Comment: no :id is the current_user name but will never be the same a title

Comment: in that case, you cant do that.  even if you say that they will never be the same, rails won't know that.  what you can do in this case is move to a common controller which will treat :id as a profile name first, then if it can't be found, it will then try as a guideline title. ugly but i don't know of any way to make that work

Comment: ok thanks.  I've decided to use the guidelines#show and forget about profiles#show

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid